# Counting probability of disease

Tags: probability

There are 2 types of people in a big factory: prone to COVID (30% of workers), and nonprone to COVID (70% of workers). For a COVID-prone person, p(COVID) = $0.4$. For a nonprone to COVID person, p(COVID) = $0.2$.

Compute:

a) the probability a random factory worker will have a COVID

b) given a person who has a COVID, what is p(person is COVID-prone).

I'm not sure, should I use binomial probability or usual, or how I should count in general. I suppose in (a) I need to calculate $0.3*0.4 + 0.7*0.2 = 0.26$

Comment: You just need the law of total probability.

Comment: For (b), you use the definition of condition probability: p(A given B) = p(A and B) $\div$ p(B), or $P(A | B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$

Answer (score 1):

For a) you are correct. The probability that someone has Covid is the sum of the probability for a covid-prone person to get it, plus the probability for a non-prone person to get it, or
$$0.4\times 0.3 +0.2\times 0.7 = 0.26$$

For b) you want to know the probability for a person who has covid to be covid-prone. The probability to have covid if you are prone is
$$0.4\times 0.3$$and since you know that the person has already covid you divide by the probability of the known event calculated above (see [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability))
$$\dfrac{0.4\times 0.3}{0.26} \approx 0.4615$$

Answer (score 1):

If we write everything we know, we got :

$P(Covid~\vert~prone~Covid) = 0.4 $

$P(prone~Covid) = 0.3$

$P(non-prone~Covid) = 0.7$

$P(Covid~\vert~non-prone~Covid) = 0.2$

We can deduce : $P(Covid) = P(Covid\bigcap prone~Covid) + P(Covid \bigcap non-prone~ Covid)$

This expression corresponds to the answer you found for a)

For b) : You have to calculate $P(prone~Covid \vert ~Covid)$ using what you found previously